# how to plot groupped dataframe by date

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I have a grouped by `['supplier','date_order']`  as

```
                                    Amount
date_order  2011        2012            2013            2014            2015            2016            2017
supplier                            
fourni  0.000           1667750.000     4243250.000     2530000.000     2080000.000     1036200.000     1217400.000
supp_f  5289670.200     13076233.400    14199000.000    13181860.000    16177800.000    14525880.000    1346400.000
ifou    662250.000      2135750.000     2184150.000     1829800.000     1947880.000     1424820.000     1836100.000
```

How can get the plot of Amount of  suppliers by years for each line in a **line plot** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need select `MultiIndex` first for `DataFrame` and then [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df['Amount'].plot()
```

Or add `Amount` for remove `MultiIndex` in columns (change by your aggregate function):

```
df.groupby(['supplier','date_order'])['Amount'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0).plot()
```

EDIT:

For transpose use:

```
df['Amount'].T.plot()
```

Comment: that will plot the columns, I want to plot each line in as a line in the plot

Comment: Then use `df['Amount'].T.plot()`

Comment: Or `df.groupby(['date_order', 'supplier'])['Amount'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0).plot()`

Comment: @jazrael that's work 
can you add that T to the answer